# Question of controlling multiple ARDrones in tum_simulator

Tags: ros, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am currently working on the package of tum_simulator, I would like to spawn multiple ardrones in gazebo and control them seperately.

I managed to fix all the topics, tf and two ardrones were spawned correctly. And the first ardrone can take off, land and be controlled correctly. But when I tried to send a take-off command to the second ardrone, the first one just flew away. (The first ardrone's velocity along z axis just kept rising and the altitude of its navdata finally rise to 3000.)

Do you have any idea about how can I fix that problem? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194057/question-of-controlling-multiple-ardrones-in-tum_simulator/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found out what's wrong. It was the problem with the base_links' body name. Each ArDrone seems to have the same base_link body name. But it strange that each Ardrone should belongs to different namespaces. But anyhow, just rewrite the urdf files and make sure every base_link name of each ArDrone is different, which should solve all the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) with karma: 140 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tradeA](https://answers.ros.org/users/28971/tradea/) on 2018-01-15**:
What version of ROS version were you using? I'm trying to create a similar setup for ROS Kinetic + Gazebo7